# How to Select All Columns from Azure Mobile Service in Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using the .Net backend for Azure Mobile Service. I can successfully run the following query, and it returns all items from the database however it only returns the items with their IDs and no other columns are returns, they are all set to null

```
TableName.execute(new TableQueryCallback<ClassName>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<ClassName> result, int count,
                                    Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response)
```

So do I need to supply a select filter or should I be using the TableOperationsCallback? There is no error, it just returns all the columns as null except for the id column

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the casing of the fields match between the client and the server. By default the .NET backend will make all properties camel-case, so that if you have this class:

```
public class Person : EntityData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then the JSON response in a GET operation will look something like this:

```
[
    { "id":"the-first-id", "name":"John Doe", "age":33 },
    { "id":"the-first-id", "name":"Jane Roe", "age":34 }
]
```

So you need to define in your Android application a type where the field is either named in lower case, or properly tagged with the `@SerializeName` annotation, like in the example below (you don't need to do that for the `id` property as it's special-cased by the SDK):

```
public class Person {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String Id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String Name;

    @SerializedName("age")
    public String Age;
}
```

Comment: Carlos that was it, thanks for the rescue. Very very helpful.